# Is there a way to do a SELECT to_char(t.columnName, Format), t.* FROM Table t without selecting columnName twice?

Tags: sql, select

I have tables with 50+ columns, some of which are dates.
For these date column, I have to apply the TO_CHAR function to get a specific format.

I still want to select all the other columns.

The following line allows me to do that BUT columnName will appear twice which seems quite normal to me.

```
select to_char(t.columnName,'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss.FF') as columnName, t.* 
FROM Table t;
```

Is there a way to do a `SELECT to_char(t.a,format), [* except a]`?

Comment: What DBMS are you using ?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, SQL doesn't allow except-like constructs for defining the columns in the result set.

Since you seem to be using Oracle (to_char() is a Oracle-specific function), you can use the data dictionary to obtain the list of columns and create your SQL statement dynamically:

```
-- test data
create table test_format(pk number not null primary key, val_num number, val_text varchar2(50 char), val_date date);
insert into test_format(pk, val_num, val_text, val_date) values (1, 2, 'Test row', date '2019-10-25');
commit;

-- get SQL statement
with tab_cols as (
  select
    case when column_name = 'VAL_DATE' then 'to_char(' || column_name || ', ''YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss'') as ' || column_name
    else column_name
    end as column_name
  from user_tab_cols
  where table_name = 'TEST_FORMAT'
)
select 'select ' || listagg(tc.column_name, ',') within group(order by column_name) || ' from test_format' as sql
from tab_cols tc;
```

Comment: This can be [pg sql too](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/functions-formatting.html)